# How Do We Solve $\sum_{i\ge 0}y^{(i)}=f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First, we know that the homogeneous version must be solved ($f(x)=0$). That equation is $$\sum_{i\ge 0}y^{(i)}=0,$$ and we can solve it (hopefully) by power series (defining the following) $$y:=\sum_{j\ge 0}A_{j}x^j.$$

Using that definition,
$$\sum_{i,j\ge 0}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\left(A_j x^j\right)=0.$$ For convenience, let $$C_{i,j}:=\prod_{j\ge 0}j-i.$$ According to superposition principle, since the original equation reduces to $$\sum_{i,j\ge 0}A_jC_{i,j}\cdot x^{j-i}=0,$$ we must have that $$A_jC_{i,j}=0 \quad i,j\in \mathbb{N}.$$

That means three possible cases: 1) $A_j=0$, 2) $C_{i,j}=0$, or 3) both $A_j=0$ and $C_{i,j}=0$. This is where things confuse me. Wikipedia says that this part is solvable only if we have initial conditions for the original ODE.

---

I am seeking to understand:

- What is a general solution formula for the original equation and the homogeneous version?
- **How do I go from this part (the homogeneous version's solution) to the nonhomogeneous solution?** [I imagine it involves a Wronskian?]

Comment: If the series were sufficiently convergent, you would get, similar to a geometric series, $y(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You mention convergence. Does that mean the equation only makes sense if certain conditions on the coefficients ($A_k$'s and $C_{i,j}$'s) are met?

Comment: The original equation makes only sense if the sequence of derivatives of $y$ falls fast enough. This means that a similar condition has to hold for $f$. This is before one can speculate on the power series coefficients.